# PHP + Wordpress : foreach repeat html structure after every nth

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, repeat

I am trying to achieve result with below structure in foreach loop where after every two images it will repeat entire structure.

I have some basic knowledge for something I can use eg. counter++; and than %2 but don't know syntax and how to use it for my code.

```
<?php
    function dt_attached($postid=0, $size='thumbnail', $attributes='', $linksize='full', $count=-1) {
        if ($postid<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
        if ($images = get_children(array(
            'post_parent' => $postid,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => $count,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))

            foreach($images as $image) {
                $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'thumbnail');
                $small_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'midium');
                $big_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'full');
                ?>

                <div class="mainrow">

                    <div class="block">
                        <a href='<?php echo $big_image[0]; ?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Thumbnail 1' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $small_image[0]; ?>' ">
                            <img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" <?php echo $attributes; ?> />
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <!--[I want to get two images in mainrow]-->
                    <div class="block">
                        <a href='<?php echo $big_image[0]; ?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Thumbnail 1' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $small_image[0]; ?>' ">
                            <img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" <?php echo $attributes; ?> />
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <?php //the_attachment_link($image->ID, false, true, false); ?>
        <?php }
    }
?>
```

So what I want is if there is more than two images it will repeat entire html structure. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: So, what you're saying is that you only want the output that's in the `foreach` to output every `n` times?

Comment: I mean like I have 5 images so in first "mainrow" it will display first two images in "block" and 3rd and 4th will again create second "mainrow" and will be display in "block" than 5th image again create third "mainrow" and will generate two "block" again but one with 5th image and other will be blank (this is require for my structure) and this will go on

Comment: OK, so basically if `$count % 2 == 1` you want a "placeholder" inserted instead of trying to place an image in the row?

Comment: Yes, reason is how many attachment will be there it's unknown so whatever attachments are there it will keep two block per mainrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I gathered from your comments is that you want to display two images per row, and if there's one extra image, to display a placeholder next to it in the final row.

All you need is a count of how many images there are, and whether it's an even or odd number. Then once you know you're at the last image (using an incrementing counter), you add the placeholder:

What your code *doesn't* do is place two images in one row. For that we need to take the modulo (`%`) of the counter as well.

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$imgCount = count($images);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    $attachment  = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'thumbnail');
    $small_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'midium');
    $big_image   = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'full');

    if ($counter % 2 == 0): ?>
    <div class="mainrow">
    <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="block">
            <a href='<?php echo $big_image[0]; ?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Thumbnail 1' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $small_image[0]; ?>' ">
                <img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" <?php echo $attributes; ?> />
            </a>
        </div>

    <?php if ($counter++ % 2 == 1): ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php //the_attachment_link($image->ID, false, true, false); ?>
<?php
}

// Since (if there are an odd number of images) the loop may not close the <div>, 
// we have to make sure it does.
if ($counter % 2 == 0) {
    ?>
    <!-- placeholder goes here -->
    </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Double-check the `$images` array using `var_dump()`. Make sure the IDs are all correct, etc.

Comment: The procedure is correct, you may just have to iron out some bugs as far as how the data is being accessed.

Comment: I am getting all images without this structure but when I am adding this html structure (where I am adding image tag twice in "block" div ) it is rendering same image twice (which is so obvious) and after `if($count > 2) break;` stops the rendering rest images.

Comment: OK edited - I forgot that the loop won't close the `div` unless there's an even number of images. You'll have to close it from outside if there's an odd number of images.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot waiting for that new code... oh its already there let me check

Comment: Okay now this is really fantastic but still one thing remain which is breaking my layout is if there is an odd number images it should add one more block to the mainrow. Means each row must have two block even if second is empty.

Comment: Take a look at that final `if` statement. If the logic is wrong, switch it around. I just checked it and it should be `if (!$counter % 2)` rather than `if($counter % 2 == 1)`.

Comment: Your code is working for even number but not for odd number and stuck there. But I think till I get solution I will use your code to move on and later will find solution.. Thanks a lot